# Publishing Service Publish Item defaults

Tags: publishing-service

In Sitecore's old publishing set up, when I select "Publish Item" the dialog would remember my last settings (Publish Sub Items, Langugaes, Publishing Targets, etc...). This does not seem to be the case with the new Publishing Service. Is there a way I can turn this back on? Or change the defaults to something a little friendlier?

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not possible. It is a limitation, this data is bound via SPEAK, which doesn't have session state in this case. We would have to write something custom to store this user data or allow setting of defaults.

We know there is a wish for this functionality, the feature is in our backlog.

What defaults would help you? Would you be happy with different defaults, such as all languages, targets selected, or none. Or would you rather something like a configuration file to set the defaults.

I can add all this detail our backlog item for this functionality, and we can investigation options for a future release.

Comment: I think saving your last settings would be the best. Barring that, having defaults in a config would be good. It depends on the site what the defaults should be. In this case, I have a site with LOTS of languages, so probably no languages selected as a default. But a site with one, or two languages I might want a default selected.